# How to spawn objects in array without repeating?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flashdevelop

I have MC's  `rockThrowers`  that are added to the stage in 3 different positions. They spawn randomly using a random generator which is working fine. The user clicks a button on the stage and the `rockThrowers` are added to the stage and pushed in their own array `aRockThrowerArray` I want to be able to check which of 3 positions they spawned on and not overlap the next `rockThrowers` that are added to the stage and if so then add a new one to the empty positions. I have tried different strategies mainly booleans and calling them from their own class to my main class but nothing seems to work. Here is my

rockThrowers Class:

```
    private function startPosition():void 
    {
        // y position 
        this.y =  (stage.stageHeight / 2) + 200;

        //Start Speed
        nSpeed = randomNumber(5, 8);

        leftScreenSpawn = randomNumber(1, 3);


        //For Left Screen
        leftNeg =  (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 200;
        leftMiddle =  (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 150;
        leftPos =  (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 100;



        //Left Screen
        if (leftScreenSpawn == 1)
        {
            this.x = leftNeg;
            bLeftNeg = true; // Now if the left Rock thrower is destroyed then turn back to false on main engine class
        }else
        if (leftScreenSpawn == 2)
        {
            this.x = leftMiddle;
            bLeftMiddle = true;
        }else
        if (leftScreenSpawn == 3)
        {
            this.x = leftPos;
            bLeftPos = true;
        }



        //Move 
        startMoving();
    }
```

Now in my Main Class I have it setup like so for when the user clicks the left screen Btn:

```
    private function rockThrowerSpawn(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        //Instantiate screens before hand
        rockThrowerSpawnScreen.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
        rockThrowerSpawnScreen.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) + 200;
        addChild(rockThrowerSpawnScreen);

        rockThrowerSpawnScreen.left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSpawnSideRockThrowers);

    }
```

Then the Spawn Function:

```
private function chooseSpawnSideRockThrowers(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        if (e.currentTarget == rockThrowerSpawnScreen.left) // Spawn LEFT
        {

            //add new rock thrower
             rockThrowers = new mcRockThrowers();
             //Add object
             addChild(rockThrowers);
             //Add to Array
             aRockThrowerArray.push(rockThrowers);
             //trace("LEFT SPAWN");

        }

        //Subtract resources and update text
        nResources -= 10;
        updateResourceTextField();


        //Remove Listeners
        rockThrowerSpawnScreen.left.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSpawnSideRockThrowers);
        rockThrowerSpawnScreen.destroy();
    }
```

I understand that this alone will always spawn random positions I deleted everything that wasn't working now I'm back to this square one. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? All support is appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. You need a finite **Array** that produces 3 values in a random order.

```
var L:Array =
[
    (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 200,
    (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 150,
    (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 100,
];

function fetchPosition():Number
{
    // Get a random index based on the current length of L.
    var anIndex:int = Math.random() * L.length;

    // Record the result.
    var result:Number = L[anIndex];

    // Remove the result from the list.
    L.splice(anIndex, 1);

    return result;
}
```

So, you can validly call **fetchPosition()** three times per application run, and each run the contents of **L** will be fetched in random order and, more importantly, you won't get the same value twice, because the fetched value is removed from the data set.

Comment: hey Organis thanks for the help It works perfect. I use the function in my Main class and removed all  the x Position Spawns from my rockThrower Class. One question if you can. Say the position used by one of the rockThrowers is now removed and the rockThrower holding that position is removed how can I re add that last position back to the L array? Would I do something like  if (L.indexOf((stage.stageWidth / 2) - 100) == -1)
      {
 
       L.push((stage.stageWidth / 2) - 100); 
      }

Comment: @NathanFitchett You're overthinking (and overcomplicating) it. When you remove a rock thrower, just push its **x** coordinate back to the list. If its position is not stationary, well, attach some storage variable **originalX** to it and use that instead.